# How to open adb shell and execute commands inside shell using python

Tags: android, python, shell, adb

I am trying to execute adb shell commands in python using subprocess.Popen

Example: Need to execute 'command' in adb shell. While executing manually, I open the command window and execute as below and it works.

```
>adb shell
#<command>
```

In Python I am using as below but the process is stuck and doesn't give output

```
subprocess.Popen('adb shell <command>)
```

Tried executing manually in command window, same result as python code,stuck and doesn't give output

```
>adb shell <command>
```

I am trying to execute a binary file in background(using binary file name followed by &) in the command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a way to do it using communicate() method in subprocess module

```
procId = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
procId.communicate('command1\ncommand2\nexit\n')
```

Comment: I don't know why it worked, but it doesn't work anymore. Now only those commands work.

`cmd = ['adb', 'shell']`
`procId = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

And I have to point out that `procId.communicate('command1\ncommand2\nexit\n')` doesn't work in Python3, because this exception is thrown: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

Use this command instead: `procId.communicate(b'command1\ncommand2\nexit\n')` (with a "b" before the string), because it works both in Python2 and Python3.

Answer (score 1):

use pexpect (https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
adb="/Users/lishaokai/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"
import pexpect
import sys, os
child = pexpect.spawn(adb + " shell")
child.logfile_send = sys.stdout

while True:
  index = child.expect(["$","@",pexpect.TIMEOUT])
  print index
  child.sendline("ls /storage/emulated/0/")
  index = child.expect(["huoshan","google",pexpect.TIMEOUT])
  print index, child.before, child.after
  break
```

Comment: got error     child = pexpect.spawn(adb + " shell")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'

Comment: `easy_install pexpect` to install this package

Comment: I am using python2.7. Installed using pip install pexpect. but it seems module spawn is not present.

Comment: in command line mode, `import pexpect;help(pexpect)` to see what pexpect exactly you are installing

Answer (score 0):

Ankur Kabra, try the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
command = 'adb devices'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print 'standard output: %s \n error output: %s \n',(stdout,stderr)
```

and you will see the error output.

Usually it will tell you:

```
 /bin/sh: adb: command not found
```

which means, shell can not excute `adb` command.
so, adding `adb` to your `PATH` or writing the full path of `adb` will solve the problem.

May help.

Comment: Hi,I tried the above code. I got no error. The output was list of devices. I want  to open adb shell using python and then again execute commands in that shell using python. subprocess.Popen('adb shell')->This opens the shell as expected. Next I want to execute statements in this shell. How can I do this?

Comment: hi, if you want to open adb shell using python and then again execute commands in that shell using python, use `subprocess.Popen('adb shell shell_command')`. You do not have to make an long connection, just connect to shell every time you execute a shell command.

Comment: yes it generally works  but there seems to be some issue with my command. If I give it in  a single line then there is no output.

Comment: subprocess.Popen('adb shell setenforce 0')---->works subprocess.Popen('adb shell webserver &')----->program stuck at this step. here webserver is abinary file

Comment: First, check out if `webserver` binary file is in your phone storage. Second, try out `adb shell`, then run your `webserver ` to checkout if you have the execute access right of the file.